# Search sharePoint for specific contentType with MsGraph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need to get sharePoint sites which contain specific type of items.

As I see on this docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters

searching is only supported for messages and persons, so I would need to know up-front in which sites and lists to look for the items of the given type or use the sharePoint api not the msGraph.

Am I correct or there is some other way?

Comment: This is currently not possible. There is a feature request open here, please vote: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/aa3cdd9a-b9f3-ec11-a81b-000d3a00c008

Answer (score -1):

For the files, you can use `/search` endpoint to perform search in the OneDrive and inside SharePoint/Group document libraries. Per documentation, you can use one of the following:

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/root/search(q='{search-text}')
GET /groups/{group-id}/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')
GET /me/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')
GET /me/drive/search(q='{search-text}')
GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')
GET /users/{user-id}/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')
```

For example, to retrieve all Excel files in user's OneDrive, you would perform such request:
`GET /me/drive/root/search(q='.xlsx')`

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0